# Big Blue Button on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, bigbluebutton

I've been fascinated by [Big Blue Button](https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/). I think it's a great gift to our developer community.

Whilst it's an awesome product, I don't like the fact that it does not support Ubuntu 12.04 and they only support 10.04 version.

Has anyone managed to get this working with 12.04? I've tried on my server but this does seem to have a lot of compatibility issues. It would be great if someone shared the knowledge if they've managed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the product manager for BigBlueButton and the author of the Ubuntu 10.04 packages.  We will be upgrading the packaging for Ubuntu 12.04 as part of the next release of BigBlueButton (after 0.81).

This means we'll be providing you a tested set of packages that will make it very easy for you to install BigBlueButton on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit server.

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred. When do you think 0.81 version will be released?

Comment: Quick update: we've released BigBlueButton 1.1-dev and it's on Ubuntu 16.04.  Definitely don't recommend you use 12.04 anymore :-).  See: http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/1.1/install.html